# How to recall a method of class in An event of form

Tags: c#, forms

This is my class:

```
public class CowTypeDefaults
{
  public static void LactatingCow()
    {
        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        {
            frm.CowAgetxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.CowWeighttxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.DaysPregtxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.BCStxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.DaysInMilktxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.LactationNumbertxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.FirstCalftxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.CalfInttxtBox.Enabled = true;
            frm.ADGpanel.Visible = false;
            frm.CalfVarGroupBox.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to recall lactatingCow() in an event of my form and this is how i recall it:

```
private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow();
            }
        }
```

It shows no error and program runs but the code doesn't work and my text boxes are still disabled.

I don't know how fix it, thanks a lot for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are re-initiating `Form1 frm = new Form1();` in the static method, so that in each call `frm` will be different. Since this file is a separate class better option is to pass the object. So the method signature will be like:

```
 public static void LactatingCow(Form1 frm)
     {
        frm.CowAgetxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.CowWeighttxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.DaysPregtxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.BCStxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.DaysInMilktxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.LactationNumbertxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.FirstCalftxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.CalfInttxtBox.Enabled = true;
        frm.ADGpanel.Visible = false;
        frm.CalfVarGroupBox.Enabled = false;
    }
```

And the button click will be :

```
private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you're creating a new instance of `Form1` everytime. Pass your form's instance as reference to you method:

```
public static void LactatingCow(Form1 form)
{
    form.CowAgetxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.CowWeighttxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.DaysPregtxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.BCStxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.DaysInMilktxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.LactationNumbertxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.FirstCalftxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.CalfInttxtBox.Enabled = true;
    form.ADGpanel.Visible = false;
    form.CalfVarGroupBox.Enabled = false;
}
```

and call it using `this` as well:

```
private void CowTypeSelect_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CowTypeSelect.SelectedIndex == 0)
        CowTypeDefaults.LactatingCow(this);
}
```

Comment: `CowTypeDefaults` is a separate class not in the code behind. so this may not help

Comment: tanks for your answer, I do as you told but it shows error Error CS0026 Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: @ehh yeah I figured it out a bit late, thanks anyways.

Comment: Just removed my comment since I saw you fixed it

Comment: @un-lucky yes un-lucky is right, CowTypeDefault is in a separate class, so how should I fix my problem ?

Comment: @MojtabaSH I've edited the answer, try the code. Now we both have exactly same answers by the way.

Comment: Again `this.LactatingCow()` will give you another error  since the code behind doesn't contains definition for `LactatingCow()`

Answer (score 0):

I think define a delegate can slove you question. 
Define a delegate base on you target method, and declare a public varable of that delegate in class Form, named it Degegate temporary. When Form frm = new Form();  use  frm.Delegate receive target method, then execcute that delegate varable in you class Form 's event which you need. I'm answer you question on mobelphone, so I can't change code style, sorry